# Altitude at which Falcon boosters go subsonic during reentry

Tags: spacex, falcon-9

Is there a distinct altitude at which Falcon boosters goes subsonic during reentry? If so, which is it? Is it +/- the same altitude for every flight?

Comment: I can't think of a reason to change the timing/altitude of retro engine firings from some optimal  value (safety, minimize required fuel, etc)